# How is it usually referred to a design kit made for specific campaign or product?

Tags: branding

So the business has already its Brand Identity Kit. This defines the general guidelines.

Now let say the business wants to use a style variant for social media and display ads. Every post should be based on that specific predefined style.

So what's the popular term to refer to those specific and temporary design kits?
Take for example this one:
https://www.disruptivestatic.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/nike-display-ads-examples.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [A Style Guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide).

> A style guide or manual of style is a set of standards for the writing, formatting and design of documents. It is often called a style sheet, although that term also has other meanings. The standards can be applied either for general use, or be required usage for an individual publication, a particular organization, or a specific field.
>
> A style guide establishes standard style requirements to improve communication by ensuring consistency both within a document, and across multiple documents. Because practices vary, a style guide may set out standards to be used in areas such as punctuation, capitalization, citing sources, formatting of numbers and dates, table appearance and other areas. The style guide may require certain best practices in usage, language composition, visual composition, orthography and typography. For academic and technical documents, a guide may also enforce the best practice in ethics (such as authorship, research ethics, and disclosure), pedagogy (such as exposition and clarity), and compliance (technical and regulatory).